# Calling class inside adapter return NullPointexception in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to call another class inside my adapter (getview method) with event of `setOnClickListener`
but it gives me `java.lang.NullPointException`

here is my adapter getview method:

```
ImageButton bIntent = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.bIntent);
bIntent.setTag(position);
bIntent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity.getParent(),MyClass.class);
        Bundle MyBundle = new Bundle();
        MyBundle.putInt("Key","200");
        myIntent.putExtras(MyBundle);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent );
    }
});
```

but when i use this function in my fragment no error apear and it works.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyClass.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and error log :

```
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/dalvikvm(3021): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2823)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at com.Myapp.MyAdapter$2.onClick(MyAdapter.java:224)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-28 13:57:54.023: W/System.err(3021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the error log as well.

Comment: srry , i added the log

Comment: check whether you initialized **activity** in your adapter class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `activity` object is null here.

That too in your code `MyBundle.putInt("Key","200");`

you are passing two strings.`putInt` doesn't accept it..make `200` as int

change your method like this..

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Context context = view.getContext();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,MyClass.class);
    Bundle MyBundle = new Bundle();
    MyBundle.putInt("Key",200);
    myIntent.putExtras(MyBundle);
    context.startActivity(myIntent );
}
```